# How to access apache behind home router?

Tags: windows, router, home-networking, apache-http-server, port-forwarding

I have public IP **89.103.xxx.yyy**, then router and home network with **192.168.1.zz**
My router is set to portforward every **8056** on ip adress **192.168.1.5** (my PC), where apache is running. Apache listen is set to:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
Listen 192.168.1.5:8056
```

When i try:

```
Listen 89.103.xxx.yyy:8056
```

I get message "unexpected end of apache" (I'm using easyphp for windows).

**Added**: When i try to access 89.103.xxx.yyy via browser, it's prompting router request for authorization to access router web-settings. And when i try 89.103.xxx.yyy:8056, browser says that connection timed out =(

Comment: Check firewall settings as well.

Comment: My only windows fireawall is off =)

Comment: AV software will also have firewall...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to configure apache to listen on 192.168.1.5:80 (on 192.168.1.5, the requests will arrive on port 80. not 8056). Also make sure that on the router port 8056 is forwarded to 192.168.1.5 port 80

Comment: I dont have settings in my router webconfigurator to portforward on specified port =( .. just:
Local IP Address - Protocol - Port Range

Comment: What's you router make and model ? You can also try to use wireshark on your windows computer to make sure on which port the HTTP requests are received.

Comment: I have ZCOMAX WA 2204 and i have uPNP enabled. There are "Ping Access on WAN" and "Web Server Access on WAN" options as well, enabled too.

Comment: I set 192.168.1.5 with my apache to DMZ and still nothing =(

Comment: Access to 192.168.1.5:8056 from my notebook that is in same "home" network is working just fine even when listen is set to "Listen 192.168.1.5:8056", ping to my 89.103.xxx.yyy is forking fine and port 8056 on my 89.103.xxx.yyy is opened assuming info from ping.eu

Answer (score 1):

You *do not need* to change the port Apache is listening at all! In my case, Apache listens at port 80 normally.

You must:

1. Configure all routers and modems (some modems have an internal router, such as DLINK) to receive some *unusual ports* as '8081' to '8082' AND redirect those requests to the IP where your apache server is running, at the port 80. Avoid to use 8080, 8081 or higher.
2. Put the hosts (both networks) in the DMZ (host at "DEMILITARIZED ZONE", in other words, out of policies)

There are 2 networks in my case:

- 10.1.1.1 (modem)
- 192.168.1.1 (wireless router)

---

#### Example:

Suppose a modem router whose network is `10.1.1.1` and the Apache PC is AT `10.1.1.5`.
You must configure NAT - Virtual Servers acessing `10.1.1.1` / NAT / Virtual Servers:

```
PortStart......PortEnd......type....... dest IP........ dest PORT
...8081..........8082........TCP...... 10.1.1.5............... 80
```

DMZ Host: `10.1.1.5` ← the UP used by the Apache PC network. To get it, run `ipconfig` at cmd prompt.

For the secondary router (wireless) whose network is `192.168.1.1`:
DMZ Host: 192.168.1.10 ← IP of the PC running Apache in the wireless router subnet.

To preview the site, do not use your home wireless or or a computer connected to your home network, because all you will see is the modem's router page. You must access your site from *outside* the home network (ex: use your mobile GSM internet, never WiFi).

The scheme to access the site, so, lets suppose the current internet IP is `199.123.4.75`:

- `http://199.123.4.75:8081` or
- `http://199.123.4.75:8081/mywebsite`
- `http://199.123.4.75:8082` or
- `http://199.123.4.75:8082/mywebsite`

Remember, Apache is still listening at port 80. Who does the magic are the routers, especially the first (modem) that redirects the ports. NAT – Virtual Servers. DMZ is also essential. For both router configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the "Web Server Access on WAN" option.

change the port forward "range" to just be 80.

change apache back to "Listen 192.168.1.5:80"

Comment: This may not work as many ISPs block incoming port 80...

Comment: quote the OP "Added: When i try to access 89.103.xxx.yyy via browser, it's prompting router request for authorization to access router web-settings. "